# Sprint training for long distance

Tags: running, long-distance-running, sprinting

I am going to participate in a **half marathon** in the 1st week of July and
**3/4 Ironman** in the 2nd week of July.
I am training 11 sessions a week.
8 sessions of swimming with lot of floor exercises before it.
3 sessions of running.
Let us not bother about my cycling for now.

Out of the 3 sessions of running,
one is **Interval training**

> 5 mins of warm up run, 4 intervals of 1 min/2 min slow/fast run and 5 mins of cool down.

one is **Recovery run**, the day next to the interval training.

> slow casually paced 4 to 5 km run.

Now the 3rd session is what I am thinking about.
Shall I make it a sprint training with **spike shoes** on?
Will it work good?
If yes what regime shall I follow?
If not what should I do in that session?
If required I can cut one swim session and make it a run session.

Please comment if more info needed from my side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the above regimen, another sprint workout is the last thing I recommend. On that schedule, in your two sessions you are doing at most, 5 miles (8k). That is pretty meager training for the distances that you are considering.

I would make your third run a slow to medium paced 10k run. Running long distance fast is about your base and consistency, and you need more distance a lot more than you need more sprint work.

If you absolutely feel that you have to have more sprint training, I would throw in several 30 second segments of uptempo running into that longer run. If you were my athlete, then I would slash your swimming from 11 sessions a week down to four or five, and use the extra time for more running.

Comment: Swimming is my weak link in the triathlon. That is the reason I am training more on that. Once I start swimming faster, I will concentrate more on cycling and running. +1 for your suggestion.

Comment: Even so, 11 sessions is overkill. When I swam first year of college we only had 12 sessions (Granted, they were probably longer). As long as you structure them smartly, you could get everything you need in 4-5 sessions. And seriously, even that will probably put you miles ahead of most triathletes. As a group, triathletes are poor swimmers in general.

Comment: And even if you are the fastest swimmer, it's the shortest part of the day. Yes! cut back the swimming for the love of ...